# Failing to define WIN version causes CreateFile2 error

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to follow DirectX tutorials but somehow in my project I can't find where to define _WIN32_WINNT to 0x0600 like it is now it defaults to 0x0603 and makes it use a CreateFile2 function which crashes my application.

I've tried to check the tutorial I'm following but I can't find where they define _WIN32_WINNT.

If I try do add it before including stdafx.h I get:

1>testproject.cpp(5): warning C4603: '_WIN32_WINNT' : macro is not defined or definition is different after precompiled header use
1>          Add macro to precompiled header instead of defining here
1>          testproject.cpp(7) : use of precompiled header

Comment: The warning quite clearly states to add the macro to the precompiled header, have you tried that? :)

Comment: [Modifying WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - this needs to be *early* in a header file, not late in a cpp file.

Comment: Ah Guess I'm just stupid, however this shows me _WIN32_WINNT is defined SDKDDKVer but not the version I want. Can I change this without editing SDKDDKVer